# How to create directory from one windows machine to another windows

Tags: windows, powershell

Execute a powershell script from one machine to another on windows machines on the same network.
Do not do this with ansible. Is there any other way?

I executed the below command from the host machine and I got the below error.

**Command**

Enable-PSRemoting -Force

Enter-PSSession -ComputerName TargetMachine -Credential (Get-Credential)

**Error**

```
Enter-PSSession : Connecting to remote server 192.168.1.21 failed with the following error message : WinRM cannot
complete the operation. Verify that the specified computer name is valid, that the computer is accessible over the
network, and that a firewall exception for the WinRM service is enabled and allows access from this computer. By
default, the WinRM firewall exception for public profiles limits access to remote computers within the same local
subnet. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
At line:1 char:1
+ Enter-PSSession -ComputerName 192.168.1.21 -Credential (Get-Credentia ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (192.168.1.21:String) [Enter-PSSession], PSRemotingTransportException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CreateRemoteRunspaceFailed
```

**I already checked winrm running both host and target machine.**

Comment: The first command (Enable-PSRemoting -Force) - did you run this on the remote machine (ie 192.168.1.21) or on the local machine ?  It should be run on the remote machine and you would also need to ensure that Windows firewall is not blocking PS Remoting on the remote machine

Comment: Are you sure the machines are on the same network?  The mask may be wrong.  Try Ping and see if you can get a response.  You may have more than one machine with the same IP address.

Comment: Yes @jdweng all machines connected in same network.

Answer (score 0):

You should start with some basic troubleshooting steps:

1. PowerShell remoting is only allowed through the firewall when both PCs are on a Private network profile, run this on both PCs to check:

```
Get-NetConnectionProfile
```

`NetworkCategory` should be set to `Private`. If it's not, set it on both PCs:

```
Set-NetConnectionProfile -InterfaceAlias <InterfaceName> -NetworkCategory "Private"
```

2. Can both PCs contact each-other over the network?
   Run `ping <TargetMachine>` to test their network connectivity.
   You should get responses from your target, if not then they may not be able to contact eachother over the network. You'll need to determine why not, it could be they are on different subnets and communication isn't allowed over that. If you're using Wi-Fi check if Wi-Fi isolation is enabled.

As for other methods of transferring files, you could create [a file share](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/file-sharing-over-a-network-in-windows-b58704b2-f53a-4b82-7bc1-80f9994725bf) on one computer, then mount it from the other using `New-PSDrive` and copy a file to the share.

Comment: Hi @Hugo ping command can be executed. I got below result after executed that ping command. 

**C:\WINDOWS\system32>ping 192.168.1.21

Pinging 192.168.1.21 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.1.21: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=128
Reply from 192.168.1.21: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=128
Reply from 192.168.1.21: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=128
Reply from 192.168.1.21: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=128

Ping statistics for 192.168.1.21:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 1ms, Maximum = 1ms, Average = 1ms**

Comment: @AnandArc That's good, that means the computers can definitely communicate with eachother on your network. Next is ensuring that PSRemoting can be accessed through their firewalls. By default it should be allowed through Private configured networks.

Comment: Hi @Hugo Thanks! What to do next?

Comment: Hi @Hugo... What to do to create a directory on another machine?

Comment: IP 192 is not private even though it may be on same side of firewall.